# Como testar a criação de um obj e chamada de método em um Servlet?

Tags: java, testes, tdd, junit

estou tentando criar uma aplicação web usando TDD, porém, estou com uma dúvida de como testar o Servlet que processa as requisições e chama a devida lógica, não sei como fazer o `assert`.

```
@Test
public void deveCriarInstaciarUmObjetoActionPelaURI() throws ServletException, IOException {
    Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

    HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock( HttpServletRequest.class );
    HttpServletResponse response = Mockito.mock( HttpServletResponse.class);

    Mockito.when( request.getContextPath() ).thenReturn( "/app" );
    Mockito.when( request.getRequestURI() ).thenReturn(  "/app/controle/acao" );

    dispatcher.service(request , response);

}
```

Eu precisaria testar se foi criado um objeto Controle e chamado o método ação, mas não sei como fazer este teste, alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [Documentação](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation?ts=1332544670&updated=MockingObjectCreation):

-Crie um mock do seu objeto a ser testado `Controle.class`, por exemplo:

```
@Mock  
Controle controle;
```

-Em seu teste inicie e verifique se o metodo `acao` foi chamado:

```
public void deveCriarInstaciarUmObjetoActionPelaURI(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   ...
   verify(controle).acao();
   ...
}
```

É isso que você procura ?. Qualquer coisa é só retornar.

Abraços

Comment: o problema é que não quero mocar(?!?) o controle, gostaria de testar se ele foi instanciado dentro do service e um método seu foi chamado, para testar desta maneira, pelo que tentei teria que criar uma atributo controle no Servlet e dividir em dois métodos, um que retornaria uma instancia de controle e outro que chamaria o método, e testar as duas coisas separadamente, achei que ficou meio estranho

Comment: O problema é: se seu Controle for uma variável local ou se for private, voce terá que mudar a estrutura de seu código afim de ser testável. OBS: nunca trabalhei com TDD, mas já utilizei Mockito em alguns projetos. Até onde meu conhecimento vai, neste caso te aconselho a dar uma olhada no Powermockito, ele possibilita testar variáveis locais e estáticas.